# how to update a params on jquery plugin after is set

Tags: javascript, jquery

just wondering how I can replace/update data from a plugin like this

```
  $.fn.dmUploader = function(options){
    return this.each(function(){
      if(!$.data(this, pluginName)){
        $.data(this, pluginName, new DmUploader(this, options));
      }
    });
  };
```

after set the plugin like:

```
$('.uploader').dmUploader({url:'index.php'});
```

How I can update these params again?

Comment: The plugin must have a setOptions method. If it doesn't, you won't be able to change options after initializing.

Comment: the plugin have the options method, but, once is attached to element I am unable to change some params any idea?

Comment: That's what I've said - initializing = attaching to an element. You can either: replace the element as @tamás-szabó said and re-init, or possible destroy the current instance of this attached plugin. Some plugin have "destroy" methods. I'm not sure that this one does though.

Answer (score 0):

As I checked this plugin, you're not able to update it's init settings.

You have to create a new instance of your initied version.
I'd do it as following:

```
var newUploader = $('.uploader')[0].innerHTML;
$(".uploader").replaceWith(newUploader);
$(".uploader").dmUploader({url:'newurl'});
```

Answer (score 0):

innerHTML won't resolve, you need to use outerHTML:

```
var newUploader = $('.uploader')[0].outerHTML;
$(".uploader").replaceWith(newUploader);
$(".uploader").dmUploader({url:'newurl'});
```